# How to add Elasticsearch source filter to elastic.js request object

Tags: javascript, angularjs, elasticsearch, kibana

I am using Kibana which is based on Angular.js, elastic.js and others.

In one of the modules, where elastic.js is used, I cant't figure out how to add  a source filter (new feature in Elasticsearch 1.0) to the request object.

This is what I would like to add:

```
"_source": {
    "include": [ "obj1.*", "obj2.*" ],
    "exclude": [ "*.description" ],
}
```

This is the code from Kibana:

```
  request = request.query(
    $scope.ejs.FilteredQuery(
      boolQuery,
      filterSrv.getBoolFilter(filterSrv.ids)
    ))
    .highlight(
      $scope.ejs.Highlight($scope.panel.highlight)
      .fragmentSize(2147483647) // Max size of a 32bit unsigned int
      .preTags('@start-highlight@')
      .postTags('@end-highlight@')
    )
    .size($scope.panel.size*$scope.panel.pages)
    .sort(sort);
```

I already tried to append some custom json to the request using angular's toJson() method but without success.

```
  request = request.query(
    $scope.ejs.FilteredQuery(
      boolQuery,
      filterSrv.getBoolFilter(filterSrv.ids)
    ))
    .highlight(
      $scope.ejs.Highlight($scope.panel.highlight)
      .fragmentSize(2147483647) // Max size of a 32bit unsigned int
      .preTags('@start-highlight@')
      .postTags('@end-highlight@')
    )
    .size($scope.panel.size*$scope.panel.pages)
    .sort(sort)
    angular.toJson({'test':'test'});
```